# Скрытие меню при уменьшении размера браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении окна осталась только кнопка, а ненумерованный список меню появлялся после нажатия на "сендвич"

Вот код:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 760 && $('ul').is(':hidden')) {
    $('ul').removeAttr('style');
  }
});
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.menu').toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1px;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #222;
}
.menu-icon {
  text-align: right;
  display: none;
}
.menu-icon svg g {
  fill: #444;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="25px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="25px" data-livestyle-extension="available">
      <title/>
      <desc/>
      <defs/>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="TabBar-Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
        <g id="Hamburger">
          <path d="M0,2 L25,2 L25,6 L0,6 L0,2 Z M0,10 L25,10 L25,14 L0,14 L0,10 Z M0,18 L25,18 L25,22 L0,22 L0,18 Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">ГАЛЕРЕЯ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ОБ АВТОРЕ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ВЫСТАВКИ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">АРТВОЯЖ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы когда `width < 760`, то скрывалось меню?

Comment: ДА именно так и открывалось вертикальное меню после нажатия иконку меню

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 760 && $('ul').is(':hidden')) {
    $('ul').removeAttr('style');
  }else if(width <= 760){
    $('.menu').hide(); // Резкое закрытие
    //$('.menu').fadeOut(); // Плавное закрытие
  };
});
$('.menu-icon').click(function() {
  $('.menu').toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.menu li a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1px;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  background: #222;
}
.menu-icon {
  text-align: right;
  display: none;
}
.menu-icon svg g {
  fill: #444;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu-icon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="25px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="25px" data-livestyle-extension="available">
      <title/>
      <desc/>
      <defs/>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="TabBar-Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
        <g id="Hamburger">
          <path d="M0,2 L25,2 L25,6 L0,6 L0,2 Z M0,10 L25,10 L25,14 L0,14 L0,10 Z M0,18 L25,18 L25,22 L0,22 L0,18 Z" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">ГАЛЕРЕЯ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ОБ АВТОРЕ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ВЫСТАВКИ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">АРТВОЯЖ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно используете `toggle` (отображает и скрывает элемент), вам нужен `toggleClass` (добавляет или удаляет класс у элемента), чтоб переключать классы у элемента.

1. Что у вас не так это то, что вы скрываете сами элемента списка, а не список.
2. Использование toggle, вместо toggleClass

[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: когда я прописываю toggleClass при нажатии на сендвич при  760px список меню не схлопывается.

Comment: Не знаю, ваш пример вообще не рабочий, вставьте более рабочий пример, потому, что я даже не вижу, чтоб вы написали класс active и тому подобное.